# Specify type for file upload event in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, types

I don't quite understand how event typing works, I'd like to specify a type here, but cannot quite figure out how to do it.
I cannot seem to find a type reference for this specific case.

```
private handleChange (event /*:FileUplaodEvent or something */): void {
    this.setState ({
      csv: event.target.files[0],
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

edit: As answer by Mukesh Soni stated I used `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, but for whatever reason the interface for files is a bit different for this type, it is actually:
`event.currentTarget.files` rather than `event.target.files`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event argument for your input's onChange is actually react's synthetic event.

React synthetic event types are present on React object (assuming you have installed types for react).

```
(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
```

`React.FormEvent` consists of all syhthetic events on form input elements. It is a generic type, i.e. accepts another type as an argument when you use it. In your case, that type argument is HTMLInputElement. Which results in a complete type of a form event on input element.

Comment: I didn't see it directly, so I repeat the edit from the question here: 'the interface for files is a bit different for this type, it is actually: event.currentTarget.files rather than event.target.files.'

Comment: thanks a lot, this is solution in my code

Answer (score 36):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

If you want to access `e.target.files` or `e.currentTarget.files` You should use **`React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`** as the event type .

Example:

```
const handleChange = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (!e.target.files) {
      return;
    }

    // handle the input...
    console.log(e.target.files);
}


<Input type='file' onChange={handleChange}/>
```